# ~ 'unquote' vs normal reference to a variable in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I have been playing around with clojure for some time.But not able to figure out the difference between `~` vs `normal reference`.

For eg:

```
(defn f [a b] (+ a b))
(f 1 2)
```

outputs:

> 3

and on the other hand:

```
(defn g [a b] `(+ ~a ~b))
(g 1 2)
```

outputs:

> (clojure.core/+ 1 2)

So my question is `what's need for different syntax` ?

Comment: Your second example doesn't output 3 at all! It outputs `(clojure.core/+ 1 2)`, an entirely different value. But you called `(f 1 2)` instead of `(g 1 2)`, so of course `f` and `g` look similar.

Answer (score 4):

There is a language feature called "[syntax-quote](https://clojure.org/reference/reader#syntax-quote)" that provides some syntactic shortcuts around forming lists that look like clojure expressions. You don't have to use it to build lists that are clojure s-expressions, you can build what you want with it, though it's almost always used in code that is part of a macro. Where that macro needs to build a Clojure s-expression and return it.

so your example

```
(defn g [a b] `(+ ~a ~b))
```

when it's read by the Clojure reader would run the syntax-quote [reader macro](https://clojure.org/reference/reader#macrochars) (which is named `` ` ``)
and that syntax-quote macro will take the list

```
(+ ~a ~b)
```

as it's argument and return the list

```
(+ 1 2)
```

because **it interprets symbol `~` to mean "include in the list we are building, the result of evaluating this next thing"**.

Answer (score 0):

The backquote symbol ` and the tilde `~` are normally only used when writing macros. You shouldn't normally use them when writing normal functions using `defn` etc.

You can find [more information here](https://www.braveclojure.com/writing-macros/) and in other books.